# Passing global values to sub components

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to determine the best way to pass global values down to children child components. I was previously passing in references to my highest level parent through to each child (about 3-4 layers deep). I'm not keen on this approach though. My assumption is that whenever that root value changes, react is comparing the values and calculating any changes on them unnecessarily.

The only other solution I could come up with was storing the values in a namespace on the window property ie. window.myapp.settings = {} which would remove it from the props and hence not effect the overall apps performance.

Comment: You shouldn't be worrying about performance at the start. Only consider it if you are actually seeing problems. Your first notion is the React way: pass values down as `props` and push state as high up the hierarchy as possible. Don't move things around for "performance" until you can identify it's actually a performance problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React doesn't observe your object for changes and doesn't have to. When you call `setState`, you are effectively asking react to change the component's state and re-render it. The `setState` will update that subtree rather than the whole app.

Removing one or two keys has zero impact on React, or in JS in general. In case you didn't know, `<MyComp a="h" b="e" />` desugars to `MyComp({a: 'h', b: 'e'})`.

If you're trying to pass down a global obj solely for the sake of perf, then don't bother; you don't be saving milliseconds there. But yes, you can keep your components down the tree as stateless as possible as a good practice.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Ssorallen also had a great suggestion about passing down props and states high. =)

Comment: Sorry, just one last thing. What if I were to pass references of the parent itself down to the children? There are a few properties and methods I'd like access to deeper in the structure? I'm assuming this is bad practice.

Comment: This could indeed lead to messy code. Your child would now be tied to that specific parent. Pass whatever you need from the parent down to the child. The explicitness in React is intentional. It's so that two months down the line, you can come back and still remember what you passed down, even if someone modified the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue while implementing *Internationalization* in my React project using [i18next](http://i18next.com). It felt tedious to pass the `i18n` instance as `props` everywhere in my components tree. I also ended up setting a `window` properties, but it doesn't feel right!

The [`Context`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) available in React is experimental and the **Note** in the documentation made me change my mind when I first thought about using it:

> Context is an advanced and experimental feature. The API is likely to
> change in future releases.
>
> Most applications will never need to use
> context. Especially if you are just getting started with React, you
> likely do not want to use context. Using context will make your code
> harder to understand because it makes the data flow less clear. It is
> similar to using global variables to pass state through your
> application.
>
> **If you have to use context, use it sparingly.**
>
> Regardless
> of whether you're building an application or a library, try to isolate
> your use of context to a small area and avoid using the context API
> directly when possible so that it's easier to upgrade when the API
> changes.